# How to make a Subnav with logo

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm looking to make a subnav under my navbar. I'm trying to get my text in my subnav to the right and my logo to the left of it. I can't seem to get my text to move to the right, however. I was also wondering how I get my logo to move down a little so I can get some space between the line and the logo; so it's not directly under the line. Thank you!

[image]

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open+Sans", sans-serif;
 }

 .navbar {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0C133C;
 }
 
 
 #nav {
     background-color: #fff; 
     color: white;
     width: 100%;
 
 }
 .nav {
   float: right;
     text-align: left;
   margin: 0;
 }
 .nav > li {                                                             
     display:Inline-block;
     padding: 20px 50px 10px 9px;                              
 }
 
.nav > li a {                                               
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0C133C;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
.clearer {
    clear:both;
}

  
}
.subnav class{
  margin: 0;
position:relative;
}

 .subnav > div a {                                               
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #0C133C;
     font-size: 18px;
padding: 20px 30px 10px 9px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"
    

</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Get a Quote</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </div>
        

<subnav class="subnav subnav-light bg-light">
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="subnav=brand" href="#">
<img src="universallogo.jpg"
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Bonds</a>
</a>
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Report a Claim</a>
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About Us</a>
</div>
</subnav>
 
</ul>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give these styles a try. Essentially just `flex` the parent and use `justify-content: space-between;` to get elements to be on right and left sides. For your logo, you can just give it a class and add some margin to separate it from the bottom border on `nav`. I replaced your logo with a dummy image to demonstrate.

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open+Sans", sans-serif;
 }

 .navbar {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0C133C;
 }
 
 
 #nav {
     background-color: #fff; 
     color: white;
     width: 100%;
 
 }
 .nav {
   float: right;
     text-align: left;
   margin: 0;
 }
 .nav > li {                                                             
     display:Inline-block;
     padding: 20px 50px 10px 9px;                              
 }
 
.nav > li a {                                               
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0C133C;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
.clearer {
    clear:both;
}

  
}
.subnav class{
  margin: 0;
position:relative;
}

 .subnav > div a {                                               
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #0C133C;
     font-size: 18px;
padding: 20px 30px 10px 9px;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: .5rem;
}
.subnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Navbar</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="navbar">
         <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Get a Quote</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <div class="clearer"></div>
      </div>
      <subnav class="subnav subnav-light bg-light">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff" class="logo"/>
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="subnav=brand" href="#"></a>
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Bonds</a>
            
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Report a Claim</a>
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About Us</a>
         </div>
      </subnav>
   </body>
</html>
```